# How can I route a section of my application to another IP address?

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-web-services, express, http-redirect

Lets consider I have an application www.abc.com hosted at some IP address 00.00.00.00. This application is working fine. 
Now, my need is I will have to define a route /platform, such that all the requests to www.abc.com/platform should be redirected to another server 11.11.11.11.

Also, once redirected, the browser URL should remain www.abc.com/platform and not 11.11.11.11(as in simple redirect).

How can this be achieved?

Any suggesstions. ?

Comment: Have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: The domain name `www.abc.com` will always resolve the same way in a DNS server, regardless of the path afterwards. It cannot point to a different IP address. Your application would need to receive the traffic on the initial IP address and then forward the request to the second IP address. More to the point... Why do you have this requirement? Why are you not willing to have a secondary domain name like `platform.abc.com`?

Comment: I this the OP is pretty well aware of that when describing this as a "redirect"

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty ways to achieve this.

If your application is not on https, you can do this at Network Layer e.g. by defining CDN rules in Cloudfront, Akamai, Cloudflare etc. Your origin server will be selected as per request path.

If your application is on https or not having any CDN then,

- You can do a proxy setup in Nginx or Apache.
- You can use ALB (Application Load Balancer) in AWS.

Below documents will be useful to you:

https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0
https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/